# Rails 3.2 assets:precompile

Tags: heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

After wrestling with heroku for about a week and passing through various barriers to get it working (barriers to a newbie, I definitely don't fault heroku) I finally got my app running on it. One of the steps I had to adjust was precompiling my assets

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and making some changes to the production environment in production.rb ...

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
```

Unfortunately this breaks a number of js behaviors on my local site.  Works fine on heroku though.  The way I've been handling this is to just rollback my local copy to a point just before these changes, but I'd like to understand why it's breaking.  And also is there an assets:decomplile? Basically how the hell does one reverse the polarity or whatever? I'm definitely trying to get more intimate with the assets pipeline, but in the meantime any help or insight would be greatly apprecitaed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove the precompiled assets in your local copy you just need to run

```
rake assets:clean
```

If you still have issues, clean your browser cache